# can a sequence of distinct integers be convergent? Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let {Xn} be a sequence of distinct integers. Can it be convergent?

This is from Rudin, and I assumed that {Xn} is given to be an infinite sequence since it's defined as a function which maps from N. and N has infinitely many elements, so there must be infinitely many destinations (ie. terms in Xn.) which may not be distinct.

Answer: no.
Proof: Because {Xn} are all distinct, the sequence must be unbounded. Suppose there was a bound. then call 'x' the smallest element and 'y' the largest element. Then, there are only x - y + 1 possible distinct integers in our set. since integers are all equidistant from each other. However, our set was given to be an infinite sequence of distinct integers, so there must be infinitely many distinct integers in our set. Therefore, this is a contradiction, and the sequence is unbounded.

%%EDIT
this is the entirety of the theorem. If a set {Pn} converges, then {Pn} is bounded. sorry about that guys.
%%EDIT

Thm 3.2
convergence => bounded.

The contrapositive of that is
unbounded => divergent.

Therefore, since our sequence is unbounded, it must be divergent.

Comment: What is the topology?

Comment: And now every one reading this will pull his copy of Rudin from the shelf and will look up Thm 3.2 (of course with the exception of those who know the book by heart...) -- Admittedly it's not hard to guess what Thm 3.2 says, but some help for the reader is always appreciated.

Comment: This is an exercise in Rudin?

Comment: @Thomas I don't even have that book available and have learned about its fame only via the learners questions one encounters here :)

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Or even: What is the space? In the one-point compactification of $\Bbb N$ with standard topology, a sequence of distinct integers may converge ...

Comment: sorry, its an assignment from the professor. it wasn't given what the space was. would it matter?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In this context it is safe to assume that we are working in the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @mac5 it must come from PMA, I think.

Comment: oh, what's PMA?

Comment: @mac5 "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" (Rudin)

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is correct. More generally, a sequence of integers $\{x_n\}$ converges if and only if it is eventually constant, that is, there exists $N$ such that $x_N=x_{N+1}=\cdots$.